# Repeating the last command in Eclipse a la Vim

Tags: eclipse, vim, repeat

As good as Eclipse is at writing my code for me, I sometimes find myself needing to repeat the same operation, as with hitting the period (.) key in Vi(m). It seems reasonable that if Eclipse's concept of commands allows for Undo/Redo, a Repeat should be an easy addition, but I'm not seeing anything of the sort under Preferences->General->Keys. Maybe there's a plugin?

Thanks!

*EDIT  I'm aware there are a bunch of plugins for vimitation, but this time I'm looking for something lighter that leaves the editor more or less intact.*

Comment: There are several plugins that emulate vim.

Comment: But most of them are not worth the time you invest in them. Working with crutches does not pay off.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/)? It is an Eclipse plugin that emulates basic Vim commands/features in the Eclipse standard editor.

It is NOT the full fledged Vim environment running in Eclipse like [VimPlugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vimplugin/) (which does not fully work with os x).
It just supports all the basic Vim commands for movement and editing (also the . command ;) but that's pretty it. Cool thing is that all the Eclipse advanced commands are still available through standard .

Comment: This is a pretty slick little plugin. I love being able to enter/exit vim mode at will, makes the feature much less intrusive. It's not exactly what I was looking for, but at least it does the job.